# Classpath Issue with Java

Tags: java, classpath

Should there be any reason why I'm unable to run my Java program from within Eclipse when I insert this snippet of code before everything else:

```
ClassLoader sysClassLoader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
URL[] urls = ((URLClassLoader)sysClassLoader).getURLs();
for(int i=0; i< urls.length; i++)
{
   System.out.println(urls[i].getFile());
}
```

Comment: What kind of code comes thereafter which ceased to execute? As you explicitly mentioned Eclipse, does this imply that it works fine with `java.exe` in cmd and/or other IDE's?

Comment: It's a client that talks to a service. Ordinarily without that code snippet, it's able to talk to the service, receive and parse the response.

Comment: I just tried it and I see no problem. What do you mean by "unable to run"? What kind of error do you get?